# Unable to write kafka topic data into postgres DB using JDBC kafka-sink-connector

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have one kafka topic where we produce avro records and the schema looks like as below.

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "testValue",
  "namespace": "com.test.testValue",
  "fields": [
    {
        "name": "A",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "B",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "C",
      "type": {
        "type": "bytes",
        "logicalType": "decimal",
        "precision": 8,
        "scale": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "D",
      "type": {
        "type": "long",
        "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "E",
      "type": [
        {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "F",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "G",
              "type": {
                "type": "bytes",
                "logicalType": "decimal",
                "precision": 8,
                "scale": 2
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "H",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "dummy",
              "type": "boolean",
              "default": true
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "I",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "J",
              "type": {
                "type": "bytes",
                "logicalType": "decimal",
                "precision": 8,
                "scale": 2
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "K",
      "type": {
        "type": "long",
        "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "L",
      "type": "boolean"
    }
  ]
}
```

And I have the below configuration for the connector.

```
 {
 "name" : "test-sink-database",
 "config" : {
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://database_url/postgres",
  "topics": "test",
  "connection.user": "postgres",
  "connection.password": "password",
  "table.name.format": "test_table",
  "auto.create": "true",
  "schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
  "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
  "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
  "name": "test-sink-database",
  "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
  "key.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
  "insert.mode":"insert"
}
```

Getting below error.

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: io.confluent.connect.avro.Union (STRUCT) type doesn't have a mapping to the SQL database column type
```

**Full stacktrace**

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:560)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:321)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: io.confluent.connect.avro.Union (STRUCT) type doesn't have a mapping to the SQL database column type
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.getSqlType(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:1727)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.PostgreSqlDatabaseDialect.getSqlType(PostgreSqlDatabaseDialect.java:215)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.writeColumnSpec(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:1643)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.lambda$writeColumnsSpec$33(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:1632)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.ExpressionBuilder.append(ExpressionBuilder.java:558)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.ExpressionBuilder$BasicListBuilder.of(ExpressionBuilder.java:597)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.writeColumnsSpec(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:1634)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.buildCreateTableStatement(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:1557)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.DbStructure.create(DbStructure.java:91)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.DbStructure.createOrAmendIfNecessary(DbStructure.java:61)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.add(BufferedRecords.java:121)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:66)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:74)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:538)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to the field `E` being of type `record`. The error states `(STRUCT) type doesn't have a mapping to the SQL database column type`. Your `E` definition is the below

```
"name": "E",
      "type": [
        {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "F",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "G",
              "type": {
                "type": "bytes",
                "logicalType": "decimal",
                "precision": 8,
                "scale": 2
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "H",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "dummy",
              "type": "boolean",
              "default": true
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "I",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "J",
              "type": {
                "type": "bytes",
                "logicalType": "decimal",
                "precision": 8,
                "scale": 2
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

The JDBC sink can't handle well nested data structures. You could try using the [CAST Single Message transform](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/cast.html) to transform it into a string, and check if it's pushed correctly in the database. An alternative would be flattering the value with another SMT like

```
"transforms": "flatten",
"transforms.flatten.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Flatten$Value"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick support, added above configurations but getting below error now. Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Flatten.buildWithSchema(Flatten.java:219)

Comment: Check out https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6605  and try setting "transforms.flatten.delimiter": "_"

Comment: it's giving me same error i.e Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

I am rather new to Kafka and not sure If the problem is similar to mine but nevertheless I will describe the problem I faced and the solution. I repeat I am new to Kafka and not sure if this is the optimal solution but it solved the problem I faced.

While trying a debezium source connector from Oracle and then a sink connector to Postgres following exception was raised.

```
io.debezium.data.VariableScaleDecimal (STRUCT) type doesn't have a mapping to the SQL database column type
```

The problem was solved after adding `"decimal.handling.mode": "double"` in my source connector.
In my case double precision for Oracle decimal type was enough.

Answer (score 0):

In your Avro schema, you have a field "E" with a UNION type. You will have to specify how "F", "H" and "I" should be mapped to the SQL database column types.

Try this:

```
"transforms": "unwrap,insertField",
"transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope",
"transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
"transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode": "rewrite",
"transforms.insertField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
"transforms.insertField.field": "H",
"transforms.insertField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
"transforms.insertField.field": "F",
"transforms.insertField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
"transforms.insertField.field": "I"
"fields.whitelist": "H.dummy, F.G, I.J"
```